# My method starts on the second click of the button in C#

Tags: c#

What I have is a search button, which connects to the database, but then when I hit search and the txtEstado TextBox is not empty, it should disable the other txtboxes, but it does so when I query with another search, that is to say in the second click, but I need that when the txtbox is with values these are disabled at once, when pressing the search button

'''

```
    private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //metodo buscar
    BuscaRegistro(txtCodCli.Text);


    }
    private void FBorrado()
    {

    if ( txtEstado.Text != String.Empty)
    {
    txtNomCli.Enabled = false;
    txtApeCli.Enabled = false;
    txtDirCli.Enabled = false;


    }
    else
    {
            txtNomCli.Enabled = true;
            txtApeCli.Enabled = true;
            txtDirCli.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private bool BuscaRegistro(string codigo)
    {
       
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conexion);
       
        try
        {
            String CadenaSql = "select nomcli, apecli, dircli, estado from sftclie0 where codcli=" + codigo;

            MySqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(CadenaSql, cn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cn.Open();
            Adaptador.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                txtNomCli.Text = "";
                txtApeCli.Text = "";
                txtDirCli.Text = "";
                txtEstado.Text = "";
                txtNomCli.Focus();
                Encontrado = 0;
                return false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtNomCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nomcli"].ToString();
                txtApeCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["apecli"].ToString();
                txtDirCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dircli"].ToString();
                txtEstado.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Estado"].ToString();
                txtNomCli.Focus();
                Encontrado = 1;
                return true;
            }


        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No pudo conectar a la base de datos");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

'''

[This is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA99r.png)

What I want to achieve is the following:

[This is what i want to get, but at the first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yORrp.png)

Comment: You have to call `FBorrado()` in an event like TextChanged etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be calling to FBorrado aventually?

Comment: Where should i call the event

Comment: I called the event in the txtbox